# Choosing between authentication app. what to look for?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

As many things are connected to the Internet and so is my new car tesla and with a recent data breach of Canva which exposed password, I am getting alerts to change my password but now I came across 2fa authentication app but there are so many like Google, Microsoft, and lastpass to name few.

How to choose a good auth-app that will be robust and won't be biased as Apple products are?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely FOSS Solution:

- [Aegis Authenticator](https://getaegis.app/)

The most 'comfortable', because it has multi-device synchronization:

- [Authy](https://authy.com/) ([mentioned](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/80506/76723) by @martinstoeckli before)

Additional interesting options:

- Self hosted copy of [vaultwarden](https://github.com/dani-garcia/vaultwarden) or a [Premium Licensed BitWarden](https://bitwarden.com/pricing/)
- [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) with a 2FA/MFA [plugin](https://keepass.info/plugins.html)

I use a mixture of **vaultwarden** and **Authy**, and for a really secure one - **Aegis** with a backup on an encrypted storage.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you choose, make sure that you can restore your 2FA even when you loose your device or if it is broken.

I ended up with [Authy](https://authy.com/), because it is independend of provider and platform and because it offers a comfortable encrypted backup. So you actually just have to remember your login and the password, to install the app on another device.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got an Android device, I like Google Authenticator. While it does NOT have a way to backup your auths directly, it DOES have a way to export them via QR code to another device. It's not as good as if you could put the backup in your safety deposit box, but it does give some defense against loss.